# Embedding a ViewController in a NavigationController does not have "Back" button

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

How can I get the back button to show after I embed a view controller into a navigation controller? A little background:

The "Detail" VC shown in the image below when visited in the app has a "Back" button in the nav bar which as you know brings you back to the table view. I want to have the "Add Goal" VC also seen below to be shown modally so I embedded it into a nav controller. For some reason when that page is visited in the app it has no "Back" button by default like the "Detail" VC has. how can I get that back button to show so the user can navigate back to the table view?

[image]

Please let me know if anyone needs any more information!

Comment: So you have a view controller that is embedded in a navigation controller. You want an additional view controller on top of that to appear modally? Just try to clarify what you wrote.

Comment: no the view controller that is embedded in the nav controller is the one being shown modally. which is does fine. but for some reason there is no back button like there normally would be if the view was being shown with say a push

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you add a navigation bar and drag a bar button on it . And in the function of that buttons method write

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a navigation controller to your project and connect your view controller to it with a segue (control + click the nav controller and drag and release on the view controller). This will embed the vc and its relationships through segues, within the navigation controller.

If i didn't answer your question adequately can you please post a screen shot of your storyboard. Thanks.

Comment: I have posted the image.