# Load Navigation Bar in Swift with .xib file

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, xcode8, uistoryboard

I am learning to program in Swift 4, and I have no problems with the code, but I am working on a project using MVC with XIB design files. A `NavigationBar` is added to a view, but it does not load the back button to the left of the title.

This is what I want:

[image: Intended result]

Currently, I only have this:

[image: Storyboard]

Comment: What have you tried so far? What does your code/storyboard look like?

Comment: @ZGski I have this and my swift code has nothing. I'm use xcode 10 and swift 4

Comment: Is that the only `ViewController` in your navigation stack?

Comment: This view loads when you select a button in another view. In another xib file @ZGski

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Embedding a ViewController in a NavigationController does not have "Back" button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31034887/embedding-a-viewcontroller-in-a-navigationcontroller-does-not-have-back-button)

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen your code but it seems you do not have navigation controller.

Add a navigation controller on your storyboard and connect your view controller to it (use segue).

You can use this to learn more about navigation controller: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller